# TypeError: Object of type LinkPreview is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.8, django-3.2

I'm using the following link preview python package in my django 3.2 api.
https://github.com/meyt/linkpreview

When I post a link from my frontend flutter app and attempt to preview it, I get the error as stated.

> TypeError: Object of type LinkPreview is not JSON serializable

Here are the views.py my flutter app hits :

```html
class PreviewLink(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotSuspended)
    throttle_scope = 'link_preview'

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PreviewLinkSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data

        link = data.get('link')
        user = request.user

        link_preview = user.preview_link(link)

        return Response(link_preview, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class LinkIsPreviewable(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotSuspended)
    throttle_scope = 'link_preview'

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PreviewLinkSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data

        link = data.get('link')

        try:
            is_previewable = link_preview(url=link)
        except Exception as e:
            is_previewable = False

        return Response({
            'is_previewable': is_previewable
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The PreviewLinkSerializer class --->

```
class PreviewLinkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    link = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, allow_blank=False)
```

The link_preview function:

```
def link_preview(url: str = None,content: str = None,parser: str = "html.parser"):
        
        """
        Get link preview
        """
        if content is None:
            try:
                grabber = LinkGrabber()
                content, url = grabber.get_content(url)
            except InvalidMimeTypeError:
                content = ""
    
        link = Link(url, content)
        return LinkPreview(link, parser=parser)
```

Here is the User class that contains preview_link():

```
def preview_link(self, link):
         return link_preview(url=link)
```

I have only pasted the relevant code above. The complete code is available in the link I shared.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

If we look into the error message, we might get some useful information:

```
TypeError: Object of type LinkPreview is not JSON serializable
```

Here we can see that:

1. There is an object of type `LinkPreview`
2. And it seems like we're trying to serialize it in a JSON

Looking at your code, I can see that the `link_preview` is returning a `LinkPreview` object.

Then we have (something like) this in your `LinkIsPreviewable#post()` method:

```py
is_previewable = link_preview(url=link)
return Response({
    'is_previewable': is_previewable
}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

which means we're telling Django to serialize a mapping from `str` to `LinkPreview`, which it doesn't know how to do.

### The solution

Based on the author's comment under the [OP's question on GitHub](https://github.com/meyt/linkpreview/issues/20), there is a `LinkPreview#to_dict` method which converts a `LinkPreview` instance to a serializable `dict`.

Therefore, if you only need the information returned by that method, you can simply use it.

This way, you'd only need to change one line for each method, so turn:

```py
return Response(link_preview, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

to

```py
return Response(link_preview.to_dict(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and

```py
is_previewable = link_preview(url=link)
```

into

```py
is_previewable = link_preview(url=link).to_dict()
```

### The old solution

So how do we solve it?

We have to first **serialize** the `is_previewable` and then store it in the `dict`.

I wasn't able to find a serializer for the `LinkPreview` class in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/meyt/linkpreview/tree/master) you provided, therefore you have to write it yourself.

Something like these would do:

```py
class LinkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.CharField()
    content = serializers.CharField()


class GenericSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    image = serializers.CharField()


class LinkPreviewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    link = LinkSerializer()
    generic = GenericSerializer(allow_null=True)
```

Note that I only implemented it for the `Generic` type, you can do the same for the rest of the source types as well.

Then you can use it to serialize `LinkPreview` objects like this:

```py
serialized_preview = LinkPreviewSerializer(instance=is_previewable).data
```

Now, the `serialized_preview` can be stored in a `dict` and be passed to the `Response` constructor.

> Note: You didn't post the content of the `User#preview_link()` method, but if it returns a `LinkPreview` object too, you might need to serialize that object as well before passing it to the `Response` constructor.

Comment: Hi, updated the question with the preview_link(). Though the original package contains language_code lines with an if condition, I have not used it since my flutter app isn't configured for that yet and is throwing an error for the same as argument language_code expected

Comment: Hi! In terms of the `preview_link` method, since it is returning a `LinkPreview`, you have to serialize that too.
But for the `language_code` issue, I wasn't able to find it in the repository. [Here's the result of the GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ameyt%2Flinkpreview%20language_code&type=code). Can you add the error details to your question?

Comment: Hi Ali. Would request you to check this(https://github.com/meyt/linkpreview/issues/20). The repo owner has added this when i posted this question there. A dict() to the linkpreview.py. Kindly check it and let me know If I would still need the above fix as suggested by you ?

Comment: Hi @Earthling, not anymore. You can simply use the `to_dict` method if it provides all you need. I updated my answer to include that too.